# Using the `difftime` function within the lubridate package in R to find consecutive differences in a vector of dates?

Tags: r

I currently have a vector of dates called `dates` which have been taken in using the ymd_hms function.

```
dates <- c("2013-09-01 23:05:24", "2013-09-02 22:51:09", "2013-09-04 00:09:16", "2013-09-04 23:43:31", "2013-09-06 00:17:41", "2013-09-06 22:42:27", "2013-09-08 00:22:27")

ymd_hms(dates)
```

I am trying to find the consecutive differences between the dates, the easiest function of which to use is `difftime`. Is there a function or apply function I can use in R to do this that is fast? While the above can be very easy as it is short, I am trying to come up with a solution that can take care of millions of millions of rows.

Normally I'd just do:

```
as.numeric(diff(event_date)))
```

but I need the day, seconds, etc specification in difftime.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may not realize that `ymd_hms(dates)` is not going to change 'dates'. No function is needed for `diff`. (Not sure what `difftime` is.)    `diff` is .... vectorized.

```
dates <- c("2013-09-01 23:05:24", "2013-09-02 22:51:09", "2013-09-04 00:09:16", "2013-09-04 23:43:31", "2013-09-06 00:17:41", "2013-09-06 22:42:27", "2013-09-08 00:22:27")

realdates <-ymd_hms(dates)
diff(realdates)
```